# Perform foreach in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, foreach, arraylist, internet-explorer-9

I have problem with my jQuery code.

I have two jsp classes.

In the first I define an `ArrayList` and fill it with numbers and in the second calls is my jQuery code.

I try to input a Arraylist into the `jQuery` script, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".trigger").click(function()
{
    var myJSList = ${myAttrList};
    $.each(myJSList, function(item, index)
    {
    $("#panel"+alert(item)).toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;

});
});
```

The `#panel` should get a number from the `Arraylist` at the end.

How could I perform this?

Comment: I searched through the net and found this but it dont work...
it only should write #panel1 or panel2 and so on.

Comment: You can't directly use a Java `ArrayList` as a jQuery `Array`. Also it is not clear from your code as to what you exactly want, by the way as mentioned by @nickf this `#panel"+alert(item)` is not correct.

Comment: jsp files? You aren't trying to use JSP variables directly in jQuery, are you? If so, you var ArrayList would never be understood.
Watch out! Java and JavaScript only have of piece of their names in common, nothing more. Anyway, it would be better if you show the code of your first file.
The code: "#panel"+alert(item), as @nickf said is completely wrong. It's all I can say right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a javascript Array in your jsp file with all elements from yout java ArrayList:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myJSList =new Array();
   <% for(int i=0; i < myAttrList.size(); i++){ %>
myJSList [<% out.print(i); %>] = "<% out.print(myAttrList.get(i).toString()); %>";
   <% }//end for 
   %>
  //use myJSList on client side (with jquery) ...

</script>
```

Here `myAttrList` is of java type `ArrayList<Integer>`, and `myJSList` is a javascript `array` filled from `*myAttrList*`;